# Inconsistent behavior with multiple tabs

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

I usually have SO in running in several tabs on my browser, one tab for each tag I want to see questions listed for.

In tab one I may have the newest C++ questions:

[image: newest C++ questions]

And in another tab I may have the newest Python questions. Now, when I go to the C++ tab, and switch from newest questions to active questions

[image: active c++ questions]

and then go back to my Python tab and hit F5 (or refresh for the non-PC guys), the page will jump to active Python questions after the refresh. Oops?

Also notable: if I manually switch back to newest Python questions, and go back to the C++ tab, this will **not** happen again, until I close all SO tabs and visit the page again. Then it is reproducable.

For reference, I am using Firefox 24.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tagged question page has the following behavior by design:

- if a tab=xxx is specified in the URL, show that tab and set is as prefernce
- otherwise if there is a preference set, show that
- otherwise go to the newest tab

A different behavior is certainly possible, but it would need to be discussed.